# Debugging Lua Project created in Cocos Code IDE creates "Waiting for debugger to connect" in Win-7

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I Installed Cocos Code IDE and created a new Lua Project. When Debugging the Project(F11) the game window pops up and gives me the message waiting for debugger to connect and then freezes.
Also a dialog appears which says game module has stopped working. Does anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. The console log says, that at line 620 of CocosConstants.lua reaches for s nil value. Its becouse the code

```
cc.AsyncTaskPool.TaskType = 
{ 
    TASK_IO = 0, 
    TASK_NETWORK = 1, 
    TASK_OTHER = 2, 
    TASK_MAX_TYPE = 3,   
}
```

has to be preceeded with

```
cc.AsyncTaskPool = {}
```